# Silverstripe | Insert html shortcode - page specific

Tags: html, html5-audio, wysiwyg, silverstripe, shortcode

Still on my way to muster Silverstripe 3.4 I am bumping into a challenge that I cannot resolve.

A number of pages on my site must include an audio player that allows visitors to play a self-hosted track that relates specifically to the viewed page. Normally I would embed the following html to the player's engine straight into the page's code but with Silverstripe's WYSIWYG Editor that's not an option, as it rejects the inclusion of 'copied-in' code in html viewing mode.

I have not yet investigated whether it's possible to modify the editor to accept 'copied-in' code; not sure whether that could be an option too...

So, I am now looking for ways to inject code - such as the following - through my WYSIWYG in the appropriate pages:

```
<!-- Start of audio player body section html codes -->
<div id="AUDIOPLAYER_ID" style="display:block;position:relative;width:360px;height:auto;margin:0px auto 0px;">
<ul class="AUDIOPLAYER_CLASS" style="display:none;">
<li data-artist="TRACK_ARTIST" data-title="TRACK_TITLE" data-album="ALBUM_NAME" data-info="TRACK_INFO" data-image="TRACK_IMAGE" data-duration="TRACK_MINS">
<div class="TRACKSOURCE" data-src="SELF_HOST_TRACK_URL" data-type="audio/mpeg" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- End of body section HTML codes -->
```

Note: For what it's worth, each audioplayer will have its own ID "AUDIOPLAYER_ID" to ensure pages can hold multiple players.

Can anyone share any wisdom on how to achieve this best, either through shortcodes or through a WYSIWYG intervention?

Heaps of thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the shortcode approach?

Comment: yup, shortcode is the way to go. Docs here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/extending/shortcodes/ Some shortcodes for Youtube and Vimeo can be a blueprint for your success: https://github.com/studiobonito/silverstripe-shortcodes ... I'd put the html in a template and insert via the shortcode like in the examples. Do you get the data from DataObjects? Or do you just manually insert all the fields (error prone...)?

Comment: This module is good for short codes. It adds a button and then allows you to pick a short code type, then a shortcode. This works well with data objects.   https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-shortcodable

Answer (score 0):

I would implement

- AudioPlayer dataobject with relations to tracks and playlist
- AudioPlayerAdmin to manage AudioPlayer objects
- a Page then would have a relation has_one AudioPlayer

To render the audio player object you have these options:

- Page template can use $AudioPlayer variable (the relation name, that returns object), and you render the object in AudioPlayer::forTemplate()
- Use a shortcode [audioplayer] in page Content field. The handler can check for current page audioplayer from Director::get_current_page()->AudioPlayer()
- Use a shortcode [audioplayer,id=XXX] in page Content field. The handler can check for existing audio player by ID: AudioPlayer::get()->byID($id)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the ridiculous delay of my response Greg but that looks helpful. Problem is: I need to upskill myself with SS's shortcodes before I can get #2 and #3 to work. I'll plow on from here mate.

Many thanks!